# pthreads with phalcon 3.3 - PHP Fatal error

Tags: php, pthreads, threadpool, phalcon, pool

I am new to Phalcon and Pthreads.

My environment is as follows:

$ php -v
PHP 7.2.2 (cli) (built: Feb 19 2018 10:04:19) ( ZTS DEBUG )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

$ php -m | grep pthreads
pthreads

phpinfo() says the following:

PHP Version 7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Thread Safety   disabled

Despite compilation with --enable-maintainer-zts \ --with-tsrm-pthreads

I followed these instructions: 
https://blog.programster.org/ubuntu16-04-compile-php-7-2-with-pthreads

I have two pieces of code in the same folder:

```
class Task extends Threaded
{
    private $value;

    public function __construct(int $i){
        $this->value = $i;
    }

    public function run(){
        $s=0;

        $rand = rand(1, 100);
        $sleep = rand(1, 500);

        for ($i=0; $i<$rand; $i++){
            $s++;
            time_nanosleep (0, $sleep);
        }

        echo "Task: {$this->value}\n";
    }
}

# Create a pool of $n threads
$n = 16;
$pool = new Pool($n);

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; ++$i){
    $pool->submit(new Task($i));
}

while ($pool->collect());

$pool->shutdown();
```

This code runs perfectly.

My other piece of code is instantiated from phalcon.

```
<?php
class MultiapiPool
{
    private $providers;
    private $dependencies;
    private $input;

    public function __construct($p, $d, $i){
        $this->providers = $p;
        $this->dependencies = $d;
        $this->input = $i;
    }

    private function getProviders(){
        return $this->providers;
    }

    private function getDependencies(){
        return $this->dependencies;
    }

    private function getInput(){
        return $this->input;
    }

    public function run(){

        $providers = $this->getProviders();
        $pool = new Pool(count($providers));

        return array(
            'input' =>$this->getInput(),
            'dependencies'=>$this->getDependencies(),
            'providers'=>$providers);
    }
}
```

This class throws an error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Pool' not found in /var/www/html/tutorial/app/libraries/MultiapiPool.php:29

The offending line is: $pool = new Pool(count($providers));

My questions are:

1. How new Pool() works in one file but not in another?
   There are no special includes in the working file.
2. Thread Safety disabled

Despite compilation with --enable-maintainer-zts \ --with-tsrm-pthreads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class that works is extending Threaded:

`class Task extends Threaded`

Your class that doesn't work is not extending Threaded:

`class MultiapiPool`

Try to extend MultiapiPool to use Threaded and see if that fixes things:

`class MultiapiPool extends Threaded`

Comment: After following your suggestion:

<?php
class MultiapiPool extends Threaded
{
 private $providers;
 private $dependencies;
 private $input;
... more code...

I get the error:
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Threaded' not found in /var/www/html/tutorial/app/libraries/MultiapiPool.php on line 2

Comment: That means the pthreads extension is not loaded. `extension_loaded("pthreads")` should return true. How is MultiapiPool being instantiated? Check `extension_loaded("pthreads")` is returning true before you instantiate the object.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that.

In my simple testing script extension_loaded("pthreads") returns true, but when called from MultiapiPool, extension_loaded("pthreads") returns false.

The code below resides in a Phalcon Controller.

//extension_loaded("pthreads") returns false here

$map = new MultiapiPool($providers, $dependencies, $input);

$out = $map->run();

Comment: I don't have any experience with Phalcon so I'm out of my element here, but you're not alone in having this issue: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/17359/phalcon-classes-cant-be-founded-within-class-that-extends-thread

Comment: After digging further I found that pthreads can only be invoked via CLI.